# Publishing in production aspx.cs files are missing

Tags: asp.net, publish

I have question about publishing website. The website is ASP.NET website, I am using Publish wizard. I am using publishing in folder, and then coping the files on the server, after choosing `Configuration : Production - Any CPU` and after publishing the files in the folder I see my aspx files but, aspx.cs files are missing. Why is this? When I select `Configuration : Debug - Any CPU` my aspx.cs files are there. I am asking because I am new and I didn't find information about this. This is screenshot of my other config options in publish wizard:[image]

Comment: Why would you need the `.cs` files in a production environment?

Comment: I am just asking why is the difference

Comment: Because `.cs` files can be useful for debugging as they contain the source code, but the originating source code has no use in a production environment.

Comment: Code written in `.cs ` is converted to assembly. In debug mode the files retain coz that helps you to debug. But surely you don't want to put your source code in readable form on production environment. That's why the publishing for production configuration removes source code files.